# Evaluating an element that isn't in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to evaluate the contents of a hidden `input` field, who's value changes depending on the contents of an unordered list. For reference, this `input` field is part of a [Tag-it!](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html) Single Input Field(2) assembly.

The problem with evaluating this sort of field is that `onchange` does not seem to fire on the `input` element, because the element is not in focus. That means I have two possible directions:

- Figure out how to make the `onchange` event fire when the element isn't in focus;
- Evaluate the contents of the unordered list.

The latter of these options seems the most appropriate, however it might also be heavy and possibly inaccurate. Which of these approaches should I be going for?

## HTML:

```
<div id="Likes">
  <div class="form-modal-back">
    <div class="form-modal-title">
      <h4>Choose some things you like</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-modal-main">
      <h5>Start by typing a few letters, and choose from the suggestions</h5>
      <div class="gap20"></div>
      <div class="tagBox">
        <input id="likesTags" name="tags" />
      </div>
      ...
      <a href="#Dislikes">
        <input class="form-modal-button-right hiddenLink" id="onb5" type="button" value="Next" />
      </a>
      ...
```

## HTML at runtime:

```
<input id="likesTags" name="tags" class="tagit-hidden-field">
<ul class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <li class="tagit-new">
    <input class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

## JS:

```
$("#likesTags").onchange(function () {
    var text = $("#likesTags").val();
    if (text.length > 2)
    {
        pageCompletionSequence += "1";
        checkCompletion("#onb5", "#Dislikes", "11");
    }
    else 
    {
        pageCompletionSequence = "1";
        elementRestore("#onb5");
    }
})

function checkCompletion(id, np, seq) {
    if (pageCompletionSequence == seq) {
        $(id).removeClass("hiddenLink");
        $(id).parent().attr("href", np);
        pageCompletionSequence = "1";
    }
}

function elementRestore(id) {
    $(id).addClass("hiddenLink");
    $(id).parent().removeAttr("href");
}
```

Comment: How do you change `#likesTags` content? I can not find it in your code.

Comment: @Bsalex `#likesTags` is altered by some javascript which is part of the Tag-It package. I included a link to the project above, to the page containing the example.

Comment: There are 9 examples. Which one is your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin has event callbacks for this case.

```
$("#likesTags").tagit({
    //This should be appended to your current tagit initializing call.
    afterTagAdded: function() {
        onTagsUpdated('#likesTags');
    },
    afterTagRemoved: function() {
        onTagsUpdated('#likesTags');
    }
});

function onTagsUpdated(id){
    var tags = $(id).tagit("assignedTags"); //Returns an array of the text values of all the tags currently in the widget.
    console.log('tags of',id,'updated:',tags);
}
```

Comment: My validation is in a separate javascript file. Since this will be inside a `<script>` tag, is there a way to provide `validation.js` a handle to catch when the event is fired? Or, should I move `$("#likesTags").tagit` into `validation.js` rather than trying to play across js files?

Comment: You could just move the `onTagsUpdated` function to the `validation.js`. However, I think it might be alot cleaner if you declare a function in `validation.js` that gets called by `onTagsUpdated`.

Comment: I moved the entire instantiation routine into `validation.js`, and after reordering the script calls in the HTML it works acceptably. Many thanks